# Environment Variables for Kubernetes/Mesos

Tags: kubernetes

I am wondering if anyone can let me know what would be the environment variable for the following args (I tried to look for them in documentation and could not find, unfortunately):

**scheduler**

`--mesos-master
--mesos-user
--mesos-authentication-principal
--mesos-authentication-secret-file`

**controller-manager and apiserver**

`--cloud-provider
--cloud-config`

Thanks so much in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

We can set the environmental variables in the following manner:

In  `/etc/kubernetes/config` add the variable:

KUBE_CLOUD_PROVIDER="--cloud-provider=mesos"

KUBE_CLOUD_CONFIG="--cloud-config=/etc/kubernetes/mesos-cloud.conf"

KUBE_MESOS_MASTER="--mesos-master=leader.mesos:5050"

KUBE_MESOS_USER="--mesos-user=root"

KUBE_MESOS_AUTH_PRINCIPAL="--mesos-authentication_principal="kubernetes""

KUBE_MESOS_SECRET="--mesos-authentication-secret-file="/etc/sysconfig/kubernetes/k8s.secret"